# How can I remove Wacom Driver

Tags: big-sur, wacom

I noticed WacomTabletDriver in my Activity Monitor.

I have a Wacom Tablet, which I used on a 2011 MacBookPro, but it is no longer supported.

I found [instructions to remove on Wacom's website](https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500006264581-How-do-I-uninstall-and-re-install-the-Wacom-driver-on-Mac-OS-for-a-Pen-Tablet-Pen-Display-or-Pen-Computer-), but I don't have any of the apps suggested.

This is presumably a hangover from when I migrated to an iMac a couple of years ago.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further searching I came across a link suggesting removing files and folders that start “com.wacom” in the following:-

```
~/Library/Caches

~/Library/Container

~/Library/Preferences
```

This appeared to work, and in the process I removed a lot of dead references to 32 bit Microsoft Office files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to start digging manually. If your driver setup is old & unsupported, it might also have 32-bit components you can't even run to allow them to self-uninstall. You can't install a new version for an unsupported tablet which would allow you to uninstall using the same app...

Get hold of [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware), set the search criteria in the left column to Files & Folders, Name, Phrase, Ignore Case & Invisible. Set the Location to your boot volume & the search term to `wacom`. Hit Go.

Use a bit of 'skill & judgement' to determine which really belongs to Wacom & which is provided by other apps in support of it…

[image]

For instance above, the entries for Studio Artist belong to that app not to the generic Wacom support. Items in `frameworks` may not allow simple removal, so trash what you can & either come back for those or if SIP stops you… ignore them. They won't ever get called if nothing needs them & they're so tiny they take up negligible space.
Reboot afterwards.

Make sure your backup is up to date before you start, but I doubt anything else in that list would hurt to remove.

Comment: Downvoter - it would be nice to see if you have any alternative suggestions for something as nebulous & pervasive an an out of date wacom install on a system that no longer supports it. That absolute last OS for the old Intuos tablets is Mojave… & that needs some careful finagling using newer drivers, manually picking out the older 32-bit structures & control panel, which will no longer launch.